# Approximation Binomial theorem "Again 2"

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial, binomial-ideals

How to prove that if $x$ is nearly equal to 1, then $$px^p−qx^q≈(p−q)x^{p+q},$$ where $p$ and $q$ are any numbers?

My try is this:

Since $x$ is nearly equal to $1$, put $x=1+h$ or $x=1−h$, where $h$ is of very small magnitude that its square and higher powers can be neglected… Now the left hand side of the given approximation can be written as\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} (p(1+h))p−(q(1+h))q\\
&=p(1+ph+⋯)−q(1+qh+⋯) \quad \text{(Using binomial theorem)}\\
&≈(p(1+ph))−(q(1+qh))\\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} \text{(The square and higher powers of }h\text{ were neglected)}\\
&=(p+p^2h)−q−q^2h \quad \text{(Distribution law)}\\
&=p−q+h(p^2−q^2) \quad \text{(Argument and take }h\text{ as common factor)}\\
&=p−q+h(p−q)(p+q)\\
&=(p−q)(1+h(p+q)) \quad \text{(}(p-q)\text{ common factor)}\\
&=(p−q)((1+h(p+q))\\
&\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{} \text{(Binomial theorem and }h\text{ for powers higher than }1\text{ is neglected)}\\
&=(p−q)x^{p+q},
\end{align*}
which is the R.H.S.

But why only the binomial theorem of fractional and negative powers work here?

Answer (score 0):

$px^p−q^x≈(p−q)x^p+q$ is not true for $x$ nearly equal to$1$, since

$px^p−q^x \to p-q$ as $x \to 1$, but $(p−q)x^p+q \to p-q+q=p$ as $x \to 1$.

Comment: please reread my question I make edition right now